# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error with my function, "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'." on the lines containing snapshot.docs[0].data(''),

Please help me fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Future getNewsPostDetails(String newsPostId) async {

    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('newsPosts').where('newsPostId', isEqualTo: newsPostId).get();
      newsPostDetails blogPostDetails = newsPostDetails(
      newsPostTitle: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostTitle'),
      newsPostAuthor: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostAuthor'),
      newsPostContent: snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostContent') ,
      date: snapshot.docs[0].data('date'),
    );
    return blogPostDetails;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure that `snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostTitle')` is a `String`, you can convert it to `String` like:

```
snapshot.docs[0].data('newsPostTitle') as String?
```

Comment: It got rid of that error, but a new one comes up inside the quotes stating, "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the extra arguments"

Comment: on which line did the error report?

Comment: 3, 4, 5, 6, inside the quotes. I think that this error might be separate from the last one, but I'm not sure how to fix it. - it is on the 'newsPostTitle' part, 'newsPostAuthor', 'newsPostContent", and 'date'.

Comment: Maybe `data` method accept no argument, you should call it like `snapshot.docs[0].data()['newsPostTitle']`. It's just a guess by the way, because I don't use FireStore.